# UITable Gets overlapped and the table doesn't reload in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


    }
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    if(tableView==logTable)
    {

        lbl_description=[[UILabel alloc] init];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:lbl_description];
        lbl_description.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        lbl_description.textColor=[UIColor darkGrayColor];
        lbl_description.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18];



        lbl_date=[[UILabel alloc] init];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:lbl_date];
        lbl_date.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        lbl_date.textColor=[UIColor lightGrayColor];
        lbl_date.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];

        lbl_description.frame=CGRectMake(10, 3, 300, 25);
        lbl_date.frame=CGRectMake(10, 23, 300, 25);//left



        lbl_description.text = [getName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        lbl_date.text=[getStartDate objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    }

            return cell;
}
```

The UITable gets overlapped and when i try to reload it, it doesn't dynamically update itself.. I use table reload for reloading, but still i don't get the solution.
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is your cell contents are bigger than the cell height.

Implement `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method of UITableView

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tv heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 70.0f;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

remove `cell==nil` loop, the overlapping does not happen..

Answer (score 0):

Try allocatinge the lbl_date and description label in the if loop of cell= nil and add it to cell contentview it in the same if loop.only add text to the labels outside the if cell== nil loop;what you Are currently doing is allocating and adding the labels every time the delegate method is called